# Append is working but Remove not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used append to add new div but  when a I try to remove doesn't work :/

```
$('#'+ number).append('<div id="descc'+number+' class="backgroundImage" style="font-size:10px; height:13px; color:#fff; background-color:#000;" align="center">'+ descA+'</div>');
```

I try to use the next line to remove the div

```
$('#descc' + i).remove();
```

Comment: have you made sure that `i` and `number` are the same?

Comment: yes there are in different for and function

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the closing quotation mark for the id attribute in your append statement.

```
$('#'+ number).append('<div id="descc'+number+'" class="backgroundImage" style="font-size:10px; height:13px; color:#fff; background-color:#000;" align="center">'+ descA+'</div>');
```